# How can i speed up query?

Tags: mysql, google-maps, database-design

I've created a table:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `markersStorage2` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `surname` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `id_vk` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `activity_link` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `message` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `lat` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
      `lng` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
      `type` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `id_tile` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

I'm using it to store google maps markers by tiles.

This table is frequently updated, i mean that new markers are added into it

I'm using this query a lot:

```
    SELECT id, lat,lng FROM markersStorage2 WHERE id_tile LIKE '$tileNumber%'
```

How can i speed up this query? Maybe i need to create another table or reorganise this one?

Tiles are numbered like here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx

Example: I'm using the max zoom 15, so therefore when i add a new  marker to DB the server

determine in which tile this marker will be located  for example we will get smth like this

```
    id_tile = 002013111032032
```

All markers have id_tile with 15 numbers no less no more.

Later when user look through the map tiles are being requested via ajax, but this tiles can

be on different zoom levels and for example we will get this request:

```
       SELECT id, lat,lng FROM markersStorage2 WHERE id_tile LIKE '002013111032%'
```

So using this request i can get all the markers in this big tile.

Comment: What deos id_tile contain? Maybe the field can be divided or something to avoid searching by a wildcard `%` ?

Comment: `LIKE '$tileNumber%'` ? what are you doing? it doesn't make much sense..

Comment: I've edited the question so that now  i think it's more clear.

Comment: your last query can't use indexes (.. LIKE '%002013111032') and if your table is big you will have problems I think

Comment: Sry, it was a mistake. I've edited it.

Comment: so do you have a problem now? The index I gave in my answer will cause your query to be executed with an index and will be faster. did you try it?

Comment: One more question: Will this slow down insert?

Comment: not considerable much with a single index. If you had too many indexes on a big table you could see a huge slow effect but not for this case I think.

Comment: Thx one more time. Your answer really helped a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to put an index on id_tile field.

```
ALTER TABLE `markersstorage2`  ADD INDEX `id_tile` (`id_tile`);
```

**You can check if your query uses an index or not like this:**

> explain  SELECT id, lat,lng FROM markersStorage2 WHERE id_tile LIKE
>   '3%'

**without index**

> "id";"select_type";"table";"type";"possible_keys";"key";"key_len";"ref";"rows";"Extra"
>   "1";"SIMPLE";"markersStorage2";"ALL";NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;"7";"Using
>   where"

**with index**

> "id";"select_type";"table";"type";"possible_keys";"key";"key_len";"ref";"rows";"Extra"
>   "1";"SIMPLE";"markersStorage2";"range";"id_tile";"id_tile";"47";NULL;"3";"Using
>   where"

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
ALTER TABLE  `markersstorage2` ADD INDEX (`id_tile` ) ;
```

Comment: You don't need indexes on the fields that are to be selected.

Comment: completely wrong, this index will never be uses with that query.

Comment: Hey, just curious, the answer and this post is almost similar, what is wrong in this?

Comment: index fields had select fields which they weren't used on where statement like this  INDEX (lat, lng, id_tile) before answer edited

Comment: @TechInfo: that's why you should keep the original answer as well (maybe striked) so people can learn from the comments...